# Overload string [] operator in C++ to return string&

Tags: python, c++, string

I'm re-writing a string class (called XXXString) that implements many Pythonic operations like `==`.
When overloading the `[]` operator I want it to return a XXXString& to its `i`th character, rather than a char& like in `std::string`.
In this way, I can do both

```
a_string[0] = "a"
```

and

```
a_string[0] == "a"
```

(assuming I have defined the `==` operator to compare a XXXString with a `char*`).
I know many C++ enthusiastic people will say no your `"a"` is not a `'a'`. There is a `'\0'` in there balabala. I just want to ignore this and think Pythonic.

Comment: To return a reference to an object from a function implies that the object exists outside of the scope of that function. Whatever you try to return, it will likely have to be returned by value. Perhaps a proxy object, or a view to the substring.

Comment: the alternative would be to accept `char *` as right side argument, and only pick the first char of the string for assignment or comparison

Comment: There are multiple ways you can do something like this. For example, C++17 adds a `std::string_view`; you could have your `XXXString`'s `operator[]` return a `XXXStringView`

Comment: If the point of all this is to compare single characters using string literals solely because it's more like Python, then perhaps you would prefer to simply use Python.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux If that's the case the returned string must be only by its value, i.e. reconstructed string, then I couldn't do assignment like `str[i] = "a"`. Also, this is part of a project and it has to be C++. I don't think that "simply use Python" is helping much.

Comment: @frankliuao While you will almost certainly need to return by value, you do not necessarily need to return a `XXXString` object. You may return a proxy object, a new type that holds a reference to the actual string, the offset where the substring begins and implements the operations you want (such as assigning or comparing with string literals). The comment regarding Python was in response to your statement *"I just want to ignore this and think Pythonic."* If you are doing all this with the sole intention of being "Pythonic" then you may want to reconsider rather or not it's worth your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **really** want to do this, the solution should be to use a proxy and not return the actual `XXXString` itself.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

class XXXString {
public:
    class StringRefProxy {
    public:
        StringRefProxy(char& ch_in) : ch{ch_in} {}
        bool operator==(const std::string& other) {
            assert(other.length() == 1);
            return other[0] == this->ch;
        }
        StringRefProxy& operator=(const std::string& other) {
            assert(other.length() == 1);
            this->ch = other[0];
            return *this;
        }

    private:
        char& ch;
    };

    XXXString(const std::string& str_in) : str{str_in} {}
    StringRefProxy operator[](std::size_t index) {
        return StringRefProxy{this->str[index]};
    }
    operator std::string() {
        return this->str;
    }
private:
    std::string str;
};

int main() {
    auto str = XXXString{"something"};
    assert(str[0] == "s");
    str[0] = "a";
    assert(static_cast<std::string>(str) == "aomething");
}
```

Note that when C++17 is freely available, you can substitute all the `const std::string&` with `std::string_view` in the above code for better performance

Also note that as most approaches go that extract references that point to elements inside container.  This too is subject to invalidation issues.